# build solution from command line

Tags: visual-studio-2012, build

I'm trying to build a number of solutions from a cmd file using command lines to handle the whole build

this is the line that builds the solution:

```
for /f %%i in (%CFG%\bld.lst) do set OUT=   %%i Release %REBUILD%& call :out & C:\"Program Files (x86)"\"Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0"\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe  %%i %REBUILD% Release >>%LOG%
```

the solutions are in `(%CFG%\bld.lst)`

if I add error catching as in:

`if errorlevel 1 set OUT=   Failed to build %%i Release    &  goto :error_term` at the end of the line the build crashes

if I don't then the eventviewer shows me this error:

> The description for **Event ID 0** from source **VSTTExecution**
>   cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not
>   installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You
>   can install or repair the component on the local computer.
>
> If the event originated on another computer, the display information
>   had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event:

```
(devenv.exe, PID 2004, Thread 1) UIContextHelper.SetUIContext: The call to IVsAggregatableProject.GetCmdUIContextCookie failed. Error code: -2147467259
```

the message resource is present but the message is not found in the string/message table

if I build each of the solutions from VisualStudio the solution builds correctly

I should mention some of the projects where written in VS 2010 and some in VS 2013

it's turning my hair grey. HELP!

Danieli