# VS2013 devenv Command Line Build Errors/Hangs

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild

We recently converted our VS2010 projects to VS2013. All projects build fine in the IDE. However when we do command line builds it appears to build a few projects (it's inconsistent sometimes 1, other times 3 or 4), and then just hangs. In the event log I see this:

*The description for Event ID 0 from source VSTTExecution cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.
If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.
The following information was included with the event: 
(devenv.exe, PID 3956, Thread 1) UIContextHelper.SetUIContext: The call to IVsAggregatableProject.GetCmdUIContextCookie failed. Error code: -2147467259
the message resource is present but the message is not found in the string/message table*

I know that the recommended approach is to use MSBuild directly and not devenv. HOWEVER - we are using setup and deployment projects and you can't build them using MSBuild.  We are locked in to using devenv.

Comment: What does your build command line look like, exactly? Also, is it the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24138708/build-solution-from-command-line

Comment: <Exec Command="&quot;$(ProgramFiles)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv&quot; ..\MySolutionn.sln /Build &quot;$(BuildConfiguration)|x86&quot;  /log "/>

Comment: How are you running the build? What's Exec'ing the Command? If you run that command line manually interactively from cmd.exe or similar, does it work then?

Comment: It does not work if run manually. This same exec in our build has worked for years in both vs2008 and vs2010.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproduction of the problem? I.e. if you create a new solution with an as-empty-as-possible project of the type you suspect is problematic, does that build with devenv? If it does, at what point does it stop working? It could be a UI related item in one of the projects, such as a custom command or a build event, that's causing the problem.

Comment: Will try a blank solution/new project as a test...

Comment: OK so it looks like I can build single project with no issue in my existing solution. Anytime I try to build more than one project it just hangs.

Comment: If you cannot build a solution with more than one project using the devenv command line build, regardless of the project type, then something's wrong. If it's only with specific project types, then you should file a bug. Either way, you should provide details of the minimal reproduction - what VS version exactly, what project types exactly, what projects exactly, etc. Then someone else can attempt to verify the problem to rule out the possibility that it only fails for you. Can you provide more specific details about the minimal reproduction along these lines?

Comment: I have narrowed this down. The issue is MVC 4 web application projects. Any attempt at building a solution that contains one of those will cause the build to hang. WTF?

Comment: Resolved it. Removing the MVC 4 ProjectType Guid from the proj file fixes this issue. Wow, that was an awful experience.....

Comment: I'm getting this issue as well and the fix you used I don't believe is applicable to our case :/ Still trying to solve it! Looking at filing a support request with Microsoft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue had to do with MVC 4 web application projects in VS2013 built from the command line.

Removing the MVC 4 ProjectType Guid from the proj file fixes this issue. Wow, that was an awful experience.....